# Private Blockchain Reserved Nodes Disconnecting

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, network, discovery-protocol

Using Parity I have a private blockchain with 5 reserved nodes specified with --reserved-nodes /path/to/file.

After a few days of conectivity, the reserved nodes stop talking to each other.  It is not a network problem because they can all ping each other.

I thought that reserved peers would always stay connected.